# In Bash, how can I call a function that gets input from a user via another function?

Tags: bash

I want to create a function in Bash that gets input from a user via another function. However, the function with the user dialog (get_version_input_dialog()) isn't getting called.
Is this apprach possible?

```
check_values () {
 allowedValues=$1
 for i in "${allowedValues[@]}"
    do
        if [ $i = $2 ]
            then
            result='match'
        fi
    done
    if [ "${result}" = 'match' ]
        then
            echo 'true'
        else
            echo 'false'
    fi
}


#### get variables from user
get_version_input_dialog () {
    echo "Which version would you like?"
    echo " > Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4"
    read version
    echo version
}

#### display error message to user if incorrect value is selected
#### $1 = array of allowed values
get_version_error_dialog () {
    allowed_values=$1
    echo "Please enter one of these values: ${allowed_values[@]}"
}

get_version () {
    allowed_values=(1, 2, 3, 4)
    thisVersion=${get_version_input_dialog}
    echo "${thisVersion}"
    valueCheck=$(check_values "${allowed_values[@]}" "${thisVersion}")

    if  [[ "${valueCheck}" = "false" ]]
        then 
            get_version_error_dialog ${allowed_values}
            get_version 
        else
            echo "you chose ${version}"
    fi
}

get_version
```

Comment: Are you reinventing [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select)?

Comment: `thisVersion=${get_version_input_dialog}` should be `thisVersion=$(get_version_input_dialog)`. VTC as typo.

Comment: (Not that that's necessarily the *only* problem -- but being a big code dump not focused on a single, specific, explicitly-described problem makes something eligible for close on other grounds as well).